# How to analyze this Golang cpu pprof snapshot?

Tags: debugging, go, profiling, pprof

This problem occurs about 10 minutes after the program starts. CPU costs 300%. What's the problem? stackoverflow doesn't support .svg image. Please download the .svg file uploaded to github.

[https://github.com/.../raw/master/pprof001.svg](https://github.com/smcduck/aurepo/raw/master/pprof001.svg)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are jammed in runtime (see https://godoc.org/runtime) presumably because of poor choices in the com/smdduck/xsys/xcron/NewRateLimiter

But no idea what to recommend, as there is no source code

Voting to close as off-topic due to a lack of code to look at

Comment: Thank you. The project is a private repo and has a lot of dependency. It seems RateLimiter used wrong sync import path (github.com/anacrolix/sync found in RateLimiter). I will test it again.

Comment: Glad it was helpful!  Hope you fix it